# Cannot assign a value of type AnyObject to a value of type String

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a function, which returns me an Array of AnyObject:

```
public func xmppRosterDidEndPopulating(sender: XMPPRoster?) {
    let jidList = OneChat.sharedInstance.xmppRosterStorage.jidsForXMPPStream(OneChat.sharedInstance.xmppStream)

    contacts = jidList      
}
```

and I have an array: `var contacts = [AnyObject]()`

Later, I want to run my search function among these values:

```
func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    filtered = contacts.filter({ (text) -> Bool in
        let tmp: NSString = text as! NSString
        let range = tmp.rangeOfString(searchText, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch)
        return range.location != NSNotFound
    })
    if(filtered.count == 0){
        searchActive = false;
    } else {
        searchActive = true;
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

but it returns me error:

```
Cannot assign a value of type AnyObject to a value of type String
```

in

```
filtered = contacts.filter({ (text) -> Bool in
```

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: What type is `jidList`? Try to be as specific as possible, `AnyObject` is the equivalent to `id` in Objective-C, it's unspecified.

Comment: It's `AnyObject` type

Comment: Yes, but what is it in reality? It seems to be an array of `String`. If it is so, declare `contacts` as `[String]()` and downcast `jidList` this way:  `contacts = jidList as! [String]`. That could solve a lot of problems

Answer (score 2):

The `filter` method returns an array of the same type as the input. In this case since `contacts` is `[AnyObject]` it will be returning `[AnyObject]`.

If you are only dealing with strings the best approach here would be to change the declaration of `contacts` to represent strings and convert `jidList` to provide an array of strings...

```
if let jidList = OneChat.sharedInstance.xmppRosterStorage.jidsForXMPPStream(OneChat.sharedInstance.xmppStream) as? [String] {
    contacts = jidList
} else {
    // handle failure to convert to string array
}
```

The filtering code should then work as-is.

Comment: You offer to change it to: `filtered as String = contacts.filter({ (text) -> Bool in` ? In this case it returns `Cannot assign to immutable expression of type 'String'`

Comment: Thanks, it works, BUT the problem is that if jidList is not AnyObject it returns nil. So I need to search as AnyObject. Is it possible?